# How to Bind dropdown list from the value of other dropdown list in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do have a gridview which has 3 dropdown in it.
for example : if grid view has 15 row than each row has 3 dropdown

1) bind **2nd** dropdown using value of **1st** dropdown on selected index change of 1st dropdown

2) bind **3rd** dropdown using value of **2nd** dropdown on selected index change of 2nd dropdown

so how can i achieve that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack` to `true` on the cascading dropdowns.The handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the dropdownlist. It's important that you databind the `GridView` itself not on postbacks, therefore use the `IsPostBack` property. Otherwise events aren't trigggered.

```
protected void Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl1.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2ID");
    // here get the datasource for ddl2 according to ddl1.SelectedValue
    ddl2.DataSource = GetDataSource(ddl1.SelectedValue);
    ddl2.DataBind();
}

protected void Ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl2.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddl3 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList3ID");
    // here get the datasource for ddl3 according to ddl1.SelectedValue
    ddl3.DataSource = GetDataSource(ddl2.SelectedValue);
    ddl3.DataBind();
}
```